# How do I edit an info.plist file inside of a kext file?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, plist, kernel-extensions

I wanted to know if there were alternate ways to edit an info.plist file that is inside of a kext file. From a Google search I saw, it seemed like it's not something you can easily edit.

Mid-2010 MacBook Pros have an issue related to the GPU that causes frequent GPU panic crashes. Someone on the Mac Rumors forums posted a solution which involved editing a plist inside of a kext file. [This is their solution](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/gpu-kernel-panic-in-mid-2010-whats-the-best-fix.1890097/#post-23312990).

I specifically need to edit the info.plist file for the AppleGraphicsPowerManagement.kext file which is located in /System/Library/Extensions.

I was wondering if it would be possible to edit the plist without needing to disable SIP? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All files under /System/Library is protected by SIP. So in El Capitan you can't do that without disabling it.

Boot into Recovery HD, open Terminal under Utilities menu, and type:

```
csrutil disable
```

Restart you computer. Navigate to the kext file, right click Show Package Content. Now go to Contents then you can find the Info.plist file. You might needs to change permission of the file before you can edit it. After you're done, boot into recovery again. Open Terminal and type:

```
csrutil enable
```

Then reboot and you're done.

But in later versions of macOS you may also have SIP enabled and only disable the kext-sign requirement, which may be a bit more secure than having it disabled entirely:

```
csrutil enable --without kext
```

Note that your changes might be reverted at a macOS update.

Comment: If I'm a pretty savvy user about what I'm installing, am I risking much by disabling SIP?

Can I ask what's the purpose of doing 'csrutil disable' the second time?

Comment: @CKode If you don't install anything malicious, you should be fine. But always make a backup before disabling it just in case something messed up.

Comment: Do you mean just a regular time machine backup, or is there something more specific? Also don't know if you saw my edit, but is there a reason you do 'crsutil disable' twice?

Comment: @CKode Regular Time Machine backup is fine. I accidentally made a typo fixed it.

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, thank you so much for taking the time to answer them. So after I reenable SIP, I won't have any issues with the kext being edited/unsigned, because from some google searches I saw that unsigned kext files would be an issue, but I don't know if me editing the plist in a original apple made kext file causes it to be unsigned?

Comment: @CKode You might have to resign it. You can give it a shot first, if it doesn't work, you can google search how to resign the kext. If worst then that, you can revert from the backup.