# How to use a kext that has just the info.plist changed without codesign or SIP disabled?

Tags: macos, startup, kernel-extensions

Similar to [How do I edit an info.plist file inside of a kext file?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/251558/251859)

There is a need to change how a kext works.

<sub>(Specifically /System/Library/Extensions/AMD6000Controller.kext/Contents/Info.plist needs a change in IOKitPersonalities > Controller > aty_config > CFG_FB_LIMIT from 0 to 3)</sub>

This can be achieved by manipulating the info.plist file inside the kext.

However, in newer versions of macOS, this requires either a certificate to re-codesign the kext or disabling SIP (at least partially with `csrutil enable --without kext`).

I am looking for alternative methods.

Loading the kext manually apparently doesn't offer the option to pass parameters.
Is there an nvram command to force this on boot?
Is using [Clover the easiest way](https://clover-wiki.zetam.org/Configuration/KernelAndKextPatches)?

How to use a kext that has just the info.plist changed without codesign or SIP disabled?

Answer (score 1):

If you have no problem in keeping SIP half-enabled like you mentioned, then you can proceed, but with **caution**. Unless you are really sure that this `Info.plist` change will work as expected, do the following:

- Copy the modified kext into System/Library/Extensions after authenticating
- Execute `sudo chown -R root:wheel /sample_path_to_kext`
- Execute `sudo chmod 644 /sample_path_to_kext`
- Execute `sudo kextcache -i /`
- Restart

Alternatively you may use an app like `Kext Wizard` or `Kext Drop` and just perform `sudo kextcache -i /` at the end of their operation.

Lastly, I cannot stress enough how **dangerous** this is to your Mac. Please proceed **only if** you really know (or don't care) if something unexpected happens.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! – Thing is, "modify the kext" is done. I now already do run the modified plist. To recover from a failure of it isn't that hard. What is cumbersome is that eg I rather frequently have to reset nvram/pram, requiring then another SIP-dance. / In any case, can you provide links to KextWizard and KextDrop, as they are not really well known standard tools?

Comment: Hey! Not sure if I can paste links here, is it allowed? Also, I would be interested to know, as you say, how do you recover from a potential Kernel panic if something goes wrong? How do you restore the original kext?

Comment: Allowed you should be, just try. // The questions differ for OSes, as it got more complicated in.13 & .14. Too long for comments. But it sounds like a good question to me, perhaps post it like one here?